# Не срабатывает функция при событии

Tags: javascript

возник момент небольшого непонимания в следующей ситуации. По какой-то причине в коде (по ссылке) при передаче именованной функции на обработчик события - она свой код не выполняет. При передаче анонимной функции - всё работает исправно.

Нажатие ЛКМ на документе - именованная функция, ПКМ - анонимная,

```js
class Obj{
  constructor() {
    document.onclick = this.show;
    this.show = function() {
      console.log('left');
    }
    
    document.oncontextmenu = () => {
      console.log('right');
      return false;
    }
  }
}

var test = new Obj();
```

Comment: _при передаче именованной функции_ -

Фактически тут нет именованных функций, есть две анонимных, которые присваиваются полям определенных объектов (document, this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в момент присваивания

```
document.onclick = this.show;
```

значение `this.show` еще не установлено.

Для того, чтобы работало всплытие, нужно использовать определением функции:

```
function show() {...}
```

В противном случае идет попытка использовать свойство, значение которому еще присвоено:

```js
class Obj {
  constructor() {
    document.onclick = show;

    function show() {
      console.log('left');
    }

    document.oncontextmenu = () => {
      console.log('right');
      return false;
    }
  }
}

var test = new Obj();
```